# C# - Casting EventArgs to a generic Event type

Tags: c#, generics, events, casting

I'm working on a game just for fun, I'm attempting to implement events but I get the error:

> Error CS0305: Using the generic type 'Game.NPC.Events.MurderEventArgs' requires 2 type arguments (CS0305) (Game)

The code which is raising the event:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnMurderEvent;

public void RaiseMurderEvent<TVictim, TMurderer>(TVictim npcVictim, TMurderer npcMurderer)
{
    if (OnMurderEvent != null)
    {
        OnMurderEvent(this, new MurderEventArgs<TVictim, TMurderer>(npcVictim, npcMurderer));
    }
}
```

My code which is handling the event:

```
npc.OnMurderEvent += HandleMurderEvent;
npc.RaiseMurderEvent<Victim, Murderer>(null, null);

static void HandleMurderEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine((MurderEventArgs)e);
}
```

The casting won't work because it doesn't have the generic types, can anybody help?

Comment: My gut tells me that using type arguments on an `EventArgs` object is probably not the best idea. How is the subscriber supposed to know what the types are? What actual problem are you trying to solve with this code? I'd suggest you attack it from a different angle.

Comment: Can you show the class declaration for `MurderEventArgs`? And why have you defined your eventhandler as `EventHandler<EventArgs>` rather than `EventHandler<MurderEventArgs>` if you want to use the custom event args?

Comment: Could you not use the parent class/interface instead ?

Comment: @stuartd If I use EventHandler<Murder‌​EventArgs> it will also want me to define the types, which is why I used EventArgs.The class is just a class which inherits from EventArgs and stores the victim and murderer.

Comment: You are murdering generics.  Victims and murderers are objects, not types.  Derive a class from EventArgs and add two properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your `MurderEventArgs` looks like that:

```
class MurderEventArgs<TVictim, TMurderer> : EventArgs
{
    public MurderEventArgs(TVictim victim, TMurderer murderer)
    {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

You may change your `EventHandler` to:

```
class EventRaiser<TVictim, TMurderer>
{
    public event EventHandler<MurderEventArgs<TVictim, TMurderer>> OnMurderEvent;

    public void RaiseMurderEvent(TVictim npcVictim, TMurderer npcMurderer)
    {
        if (OnMurderEvent != null)
        {
            OnMurderEvent(this, new MurderEventArgs<TVictim, TMurderer>(npcVictim, npcMurderer));
        }
    }
}
```

And your usage would look like this:

```
static void FireAndForget<TVictim, TMurderer>(TVictim victim, TMurderer murderer)
{
    var npc = new EventRaiser<TVictim, TMurderer>();
    npc.OnMurderEvent += HandleMurderEvent<TVictim,TMurderer>;
    npc.OnMurderEvent += HandleMurderEventAlt;
    npc.RaiseMurderEvent(victim, murderer);
}

static void HandleMurderEvent<TVictim, TMurderer>(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var murderEvent = (MurderEventArgs<TVictim, TMurderer>)e;
    //do something with the event
}

//or alternatively
static void HandleMurderEventAlt<TVictim, TMurderer>(object sender, MurderEventArgs<TVictim, TMurderer> e)
{
    //do something with the event
}
```

#### some afterthoughts

I named it `FireAndForget` for a reason. You need create a new `EventRaiser` instance for each type combination of `TVictim` and `TMurderer` or re-use an already existing instance for a combination. But that defeats the purpose of an EventListener in my opinion.

You can alternatively create a `public void Murder<TVictim, TMurderer>(TVictim victim, TMurderer murderer)` method and do your stuff there. No need for an event at all. Drawback: a `TMurderer` needs to be forced to call that method.

Or implement `MurdererBy<TMurderer>(TMurderer murderer)` at any `TVictim` class and raise a *MurderedByEvent*. Drawback: a `TVictim` *"knows"* the `TMurderer`. Let `TMurderer` implement a `Murders<TVictim>(TVictim victim)` method but who enforces that the murder is registered?

Or create some kind of *LifeCycleManager*, `TVictim`'s can only be created by that Manager (Factory pattern). On each instance creation the Manager registers its own EventListener to the *MurderedByEvent* of the new `TVictim` instance.

#### summary

My sample code from above *answers* your question to some extend but you should re-think your model. Who needs to know of the event? Should every murder be known? What happens to the victim?

What is required to be known for a *murder* event? Name of the victim and murderer only then go with an interface model proposed by the other authors.

Comment: Thank you, I am using this method for my game :)

Comment: @Luna added some afterthoughts

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure without seeing more of your code, but since it seems like the type params TVictim, TMurderer of the second code snippet correspond to the concrete types Victim, Murderer then perhaps your second snippet just needs to be changed to the following:

```
npc.OnMurderEvent += HandleMurderEvent;
npc.RaiseMurderEvent<Victim, Murderer>(null, null);

static void HandleMurderEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine((MurderEventArgs<Victim, Murderer>)e);
}
```

In reply to your comment, to remove the generics (which seems to be what most people are recommending here), you would change MurderEventArgs to something like:

```
public class MurderEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MurderEventArgs(IPerson victim, IPerson murderer)
    {
        Victim = victim;
        Murderer = murderer;
    }
    public IPerson Victim { get; }
    public IPerson Murderer { get; }
}
```

Where the events are raised, it would be something like:

```
public event EventHandler<MurderEventArgs> OnMurderEvent;

public void RaiseMurderEvent(IPerson npcVictim, IPerson npcMurderer)
{
    if (OnMurderEvent != null)
        OnMurderEvent(this, new MurderEventArgs(npcVictim, npcMurderer));
}
```

There would be some common information in the IPerson interface and then more in the specialised implementations -

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public abstract class Person : IPerson
{
    protected Person (string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
}

public class Adult : Person
{
    public Adult(string name) : base(name) { }
}

public class Child : Person
{
    public Child(string name, int age) : base(name)
    {
        Age = age
    }
    public int Age { get; }
}
```

Finally, the event listening code will be something along these lines:

```
npc.OnMurderEvent += Npc_OnMurderEvent;
npc.RaiseMurderEvent(victim, murderer);

private static void Npc_OnMurderEvent(object sender, MurderEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Victim.Name + " was murdered by " + e.Murderer.Name);
    var murdererAsChild = e.Murderer as Child;
    if (murdererAsChild != null)
        Console.WriteLine(".. who is only a child, it must be Damien!");

    // Deal with any other special cases for particular Victim, Murderer combinations..
}
```

As you asked in a comment on the answer by @romain-aga (who I shamelessly stole the IPerson interface name from!), it would be necessary to perform runtime casting if you were interested in murderers or victims that were of more specific types.

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't, I have a few case where it could end up as: MurderEventArgs<Doctor, Student>

Comment: If you can't know at compile what the type params will be then you might be better changing MurderEventArgs and RaiseMurderEvent so that they are not generic, which will mean that you will have to do runtime type checking on the npcVictim and npcMurderer values (which is basically what @Glorin Oakenfoot said in his first comment).

Comment: Could you possible post an answer, showing how I could do it a different way? Thank you.

Comment: I am using @ckerth's method as I would like to avoid having loads of checks when type-casting. By the way, what is the point of using "protected", I don't really understand what that keyword does.

Comment: Protected is like private except that it's available to any derived class. Since Person is an abstract class, it can't be instantiated directly and so its constructor can only really be accessed by derived classes (such as Adult and Child) - so it's not really accurate to mark it as public and so I tend to make them as protected.

Answer (score 1):

With interfaces you can get a workaround.

If your classes: Doctor, Student, Teacher, etc... implement or inherit from the same interface/class, you could write:

```
public event EventHandler<MurderEventArgs> OnMurderEvent;

public void RaiseMurderEvent(IPerson npcVictim, IPerson npcMurderer)
{
    if (OnMurderEvent != null)
    {
        OnMurderEvent(this, new MurderEventArgs(npcVictim, npcMurderer));
    }
}
```

and do that:

```
npc.OnMurderEvent += HandleMurderEvent;
npc.RaiseMurderEvent(null, null);

static void HandleMurderEvent(object sender, MurderEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

For your class hierarchy, you could have something like that:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    // All the methods/properties that make a person
}

public abstract class Person : IPerson
{
    // All the common implementations
}

public class Doctor/Student/Teacher/etc... : Person
{
    // All the specific implementations
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like I can access anything that isn't part of the IPerson, am   I supposed to be casting this

Comment: It really depends on your implementation. We don't have enough information here, to know if this can work for you. But in lot of cases, it works.

Comment: And you don't need to know what type you are manipulating, just that they are an IPerson. Even for the @ckerth method an interface could be useful, since you can pass anything to your method, even an int... you should use a generic constraint on TVictim and TMurderer, to avoid this kind of cases.